# Pandas - Absolute value for header row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an issue reading some poorly structured excel templates.

I intend for my process to make use of a metadata file containing 4 fields: Filename, Type, Sheet ID, and Header row.

My process will read this metadata then pass it to the `pd.read_excel` function like so:

```
pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=sheet_id, header=header_row, skiprows=header_row)
```

However, `pandas` does not take the absolute value from `header_row` but instead (I am guessing) tries to remove all blank rows before what it deems to be the header—This means that the dataframe is offset by an unusual amount that varies from template to template.

How do I get pandas to start the dataframe with the absolute value of the header that I pass into the `pd.read_excel` function?

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath

def read_worksheet(filename, sheet_id, header_row):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=sheet_id, header=header_row,skiprows=header_row)
    return df



if __name__=='__main__':

    meta_filename='document_meta_new.xlsx'
    output_filename='output.xls'

    meta_df = read_worksheet(meta_filename,0,0)

    master_dict={}

    for row in range(len(meta_df)):
        filename = meta_df['Filename'][row]
        sheet = int(meta_df['Sheet ID (zero indexed)'][row])
        type = meta_df['Type'][row]
        header = meta_df['Header row'][row]

        filepath = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))),'etlf_pattern','input_docs', filename)

        df = read_worksheet(filepath, sheet, header)
        # key = str(filename) + '||' + str(type)
        key = str(filename) + '||' + str(sheet)
        master_dict[key] = df


    print master_dict
```

To highlight this further, if I remove:

```
... header=header_row, skiprows=header_row)
```

I get the following output:

```
                    Unnamed: 13             Unnamed: 14  
0                           NaN                     NaN  
1                           NaN                     NaN  
2                           NaN                     NaN  
3                           NaN                     NaN  
4    Standard DD Attribute Name             Column Name  
5                       PRTY_ID             CUSTOMER_ID  
6              INDV_NM_PRFX_TXT          CUSTOMER_TITLE
```

Note that headers are displayed as row 4, its actually row 7 on the sheet.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the excel table looks like:

[image]

If I read it like:

```
df = pd.read_excel( 'tab.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1' )
```

I get the following:

[image]

If I read it like:

```
df = pd.read_excel( 'tab.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1', header=7 )
```

I get it correctly (I think):

[image]

So, perhaps it is a matter of the combination of *header* and *skiprows*?

Comment: Think you are right: It appears that there was a conflict of `header` and `skiprows`.   As well, merged cells before the header were causing weird outputs.     Sorted now, thanks for efforts above!